# Reading real time holding registers from the modbus simulator

Tags: java, tcp, modbus

I am using jamod library to connect to the modbus and i have connected to the modbus simulator and read the value successfully but i want to read the value in the real time.
[image: this image shows modbus simulator and application i made]

My problem is i want to change the value in the textfield if the value is changed in the simulator.This is my code below

```
VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        TextField tf3 = new TextField();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(tf1,tf2,tf3);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vb);
        InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        TCPMasterConnection con = new TCPMasterConnection(inet);
        con.setPort(502);
        con.connect();
        ReadMultipleRegistersRequest req=new 
        ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(0,5);

        ModbusTCPTransaction trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
        trans.setRequest(req);


            trans.execute();
            ReadMultipleRegistersResponse res = 
(ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
            tf1.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(0)));
            tf2.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(1)));
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(2)));
```

Comment: do you want to poll or add a listener?

Comment: i m new to it so i dont know which is better

Comment: Can you give me both example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### poll values

define a `Runnable` that will poll data

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //TODO: define abort criteria for boolean:isRunning
        while(isRunning){
            //TODO define int:pollDelay
            Thread.sleep(pollDelay);

            //here you poll for new results
            trans.setRequest(req);
            ReadMultipleRegistersResponse res = 
                (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
            tf1.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(0)));
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

then start the runnable instead of aquiring data only once

```
VBox vb = new VBox();
vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
TextField tf1 = new TextField();
...

ModbusTCPTransaction trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);

Runnable r = new ... //see code above
new Thread(r).start(); //starts the polling
```

this code is neither compiling nor running, but it gives you hints on how to poll data continously...

Comment: have you been able to start the polling? @AnandShrestha

Comment: Thanks Martin It works fine but there console shows an exception which is java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: i'm glad i could help out. You can ask a question where you tell us about your concurrency, i'm looking forward for it!!

Comment: hello @Martin Frank you there.

Comment: i am, i am... whats up?

Comment: application works for sometime and after some moment application will throw the exception which i told before and the application gets hang :(

Comment: the concurrency exception happens when you have multiple access on a collection. Can you please ask a new Question and show where the exception happens?

Comment: i m unable to make new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151054/discussion-between-martin-frank-and-anand-shrestha).

Comment: @AnandShrestha lets continue in chat

Comment: ohk @Martin Frank lets continue

Comment: can you enter the chat? @AnandShrestha https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151054/discussion-between-martin-frank-and-anand-shrestha

Comment: Hi! @MartinFrank . Can you look into this code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852628/j2mod-i-o-exception-failed-to-read